# Why was Caius supposed to be immortal?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

> At some point in the game, Yeul says that Caius is beyond death (and everyone assumes he cannot die). And yeah, even when fighting him you realize that he keeps on reviving after being defeated... and yet, you end up killing him.

I didn't quite get what happened, so my questions:

- Why did everyone say he is immortal?
- What did they mean when they said he could be a l'Cie? Why?
- How come they indeed manage to kill him then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caius and Noel were the last of a line of guardians charged by the goddess/fal'Cie Etro to protect the seer (Yuel). As tools of Etro, guardians were l'Cie, and Caius became a l'Cie by defeating the previous guardian. As a l'Cie, he had the same types of powers and restrictions all l'Cie have—for example, the ability to summon an eidolon (Bahamut) and the inability to abandon his mission—which is why people considered him to be a potential l'Cie.

As to why everyone said he was immortal: it's because he was, in fact, immortal. As [described by the Final Fantasy Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Caius_Ballad#Story), his immortality was a gift from Etro for his dedication to protecting Yuel:

> Etro was moved by Caius's dedication to the seeress and freed Caius from his fate as a l'Cie and infused her heart, the Heart of Chaos, into his body, making him immortal so he could protect every incarnation of Yeul until the end of time. Although given as an act of benevolence, Caius would eventually see his immortality as a curse due to the madness he would have to endure.

By Caius forcing Noel's hand in destroying the Heart of Chaos, Noel in effect "killed" Etro, apparently allowing Caius to himself be killed.<sup>1</sup>

> However, in the secret ending, he's still alive in the Void Beyond.

<sup>Note 1: It's not explained clearly in game why Caius couldn't just commit suicide, but given Caius's belief that only Noel could do it by taking his place as guardian of Yeul, it seems that there must always be one guardian. Since Noel refused to become a guardian by killing Caius, Caius couldn't give up his mission to protect Yeul by killing himself.</sup>

Comment: Is there any logical explanation behind why did it work by forcing Noel's hand to kill him instead of committing suicide?

Comment: @Omega Caius only mentions that Noel is the only one who can do it, but I don't recall a concrete in-game explanation for why that is. I suspected, as I played it, it was because of the fact that Noel was intended to replace Caius as guardian, and given the rules of one guardian replacing another by killing them, it put Noel in the unique position of being able to kill Caius.

Answer (score -2):

what i wonder is.....at least i believe he has to be killed by another guardian/one guardian must surpass it. they have to be killed! by another one! maybe all guardians before was immortal to? but the game itself doesn't give us that.

when one guardian is killed by the other's hand that's it. The guardian with the beating chaos heart Must and will surpass his beating chaos heart. it's not really a gift more a curse. Caius always saw it as a curse. Now Noel has to get it. Caius thought? /adding the chance of passing it forward.

What i wonder though! he said Etro's heart! maybe Etro has given a big amount of chos to older guardians but not really her heart..that was the most stupid idea she ever have had. but she lived in for the moment. As we get to see him being killed i can't help myself from thinking: oh no, goddess dead? it should really end the cukle of the heart, thus not forcing it on Noel either way as well as Serah! she *spoiler*

died after he got killed. there is no chance of her reborn, i'm even hardly7can imagine that square could explain it if they would change their mind and make her live...